# How to remove white space from a python's tkinter canvas?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I tried searching for a solution a lot on the internet but wasn't able to find any. I am trying to remove the white space around the plot on a canvas, as shown in image, but I have had no success so far.

The simple code that I have written is:

```
import tkinter as tk
import matplotlib
from matplotlib import style
style.use('seaborn-darkgrid')
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg,    NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import random

class GUIplot(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        printButton = tk.Button(self, text="Plot1", command=lambda: self.printMessage(canvas,a))
        printButton.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='w') 
        f = Figure(figsize=(24,12))
        a = f.add_subplot(111, axisbg='r')
        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, self)
        canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row=1, columnspan=2)
        #canvas._tkcanvas.config(bg='blue')
        canvas.show()
        canvas.blit()        

    def printMessage(self,canvas,a):
        a.clear()
        my_random_x = random.sample(range(100),10)
        my_random_y = random.sample(range(100),10)
        a.plot(my_random_x,my_random_y,'*')
        canvas.draw()
        print("Wow")

GUIplot1 = GUIplot()
GUIplot1.title('PlotFunction')
w, h = GUIplot1.winfo_screenwidth(), GUIplot1.winfo_screenheight()
GUIplot1.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (w, h))
GUIplot1.mainloop()
```

[Attached Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/enYrR.jpg)

I would request if any of the member in the community has any idea as to how to solve this problem to please provide me with some guidance.

Comment: You're sizing the window to take up the whole screen and the canvas is not big enough to fill in the size of window you've specified. Therefore the extra space is filled with the "white space" you've mentioned.

Comment: @RobertR, thanks for the input. Can you please suggest how I can increase the size of the canvas when using `canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, self)`?

Comment: When you grid it to the screen with the call to `.grid(row=1, columnspan=2)`, try adding `sticky="nswe"` to the call. So it should look like `.grid(row=1, columnspan=2, sticky="nswe")`. Not entirely sure if that'll work though. A better solution is to just not increase the size of your window and let tk automatically size it for you. That way it fits the size of the contained widgets (the canvas) without any white space. Unless there's some reason you want it to be the full size of the screen, is there?

Comment: @RobertR, I tried doing what you suggested but was not able to arrive at a solution. However, I found out that to remove the white space the attributes of the subplot needs to be changed.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "attributes of the subplot", but did you try just not resizing the window? By that I mean not calling `GUIplot1.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (w, h))` near the bottom of your code. That line tells tk "I want the window to be *this* size" and will turn off the automatic sizing of the window to fit the size of it's children.

Comment: @RoberR, thanks for your reply. I didn't give that a try but I sure will now given that you have provided the clarification. What I meant by "attributes of the subplot" is that a line of code like: `f = Figure()
        f.subplots_adjust(left=0.03, bottom=0.07, right=0.98, top=0.97, wspace=0, hspace=0)` will be instrumental in removing the white space.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not in business with the FigureCanvasTkAgg thing, but as long as it based on the tk.Canvas this should work:

In tk.Canvas you just use

```
canv=tk.Canvas(master=root, bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
```

Try to add the following parameters to the FigureCanvasTkAgg call: bd, highlightthickness.

Hope I helped!

Comment: thanks for the reply. I found that to remove the white space the attributes of the subplot needs to be changed.

Comment: This is not the problem. Look at the picture he linked.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I'm keeping my reply so one can find it when googleing on tk.Canvas.

Comment: @pinogun yes bro! helped me!

Answer (score 2):

This piece of code achieves what I had asked. Thanks to all those who replied:

```
import tkinter as tk
import matplotlib
from matplotlib import style
style.use('seaborn-darkgrid')
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg,      NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import random

class GUIplot(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        printButton = tk.Button(self, text="Plot1", command=lambda:  self.printMessage(canvas,a))
        printButton.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='w') 
        f = Figure()
        f.subplots_adjust(left=0.03, bottom=0.07, right=0.98, top=0.97, wspace=0, hspace=0)
        a = f.add_subplot(111, axisbg='r')
        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, self)
        canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row=1, columnspan=2)
        #canvas._tkcanvas.config(bg='blue')
        canvas.show()
        canvas.blit()        

    def printMessage(self,canvas,a):
        a.clear()
        my_random_x = random.sample(range(100),10)
        my_random_y = random.sample(range(100),10)
        a.plot(my_random_x,my_random_y,'*')
        canvas.draw()
        print("Wow")

GUIplot1 = GUIplot()
GUIplot1.title('PlotFunction')
w, h = GUIplot1.winfo_screenwidth(), GUIplot1.winfo_screenheight()
GUIplot1.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (w, h))
GUIplot1.mainloop()
```